# Making a field's validator dependent on another field's input when constructing a form

Tags: web2py

Let's say you have some table, and would like to construct a form for that table manually.

```
FORM = FORM(
    INPUT(_name = 'var1_input', requires = (...), ...),
    INPUT(_name = 'var2_input', requires = (...), ...)
    ...
    )
```

Is there a way to specify define the 'requires' statements within the form such that input for var1_input is required only when a user has entered something for var2_input, and var2_input is required only when a user has entered something for var1_input? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make each validator contingent on whether a value has been posted for the other input field:

```
FORM = FORM(
    INPUT(_name = 'var1_input',
          requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY() if request.post_vars.var2_input else None, ...),
    INPUT(_name = 'var2_input',
          requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY() if request.post_vars.var1_input else None, ...)
    ...
    )
```

Another approach is to use an [onvalidation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#onvalidation) function.

Comment: I'll give these options a try. Thanks!